# Por qué al restaurar un bd con phpmyadmin pierdo las llaves primarias y foráneas?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Espero puedan ayudarme, antes no me sucedía, pero ya han pasado varias veces y quisiera encontrar una respuesta al problema, al darle exportar la bd desde phpmyadmin y dejarlo en la opción de rápido se respalda todo correctamente, pero al momento de restaurarla pierdo todas las llaves que tiene mi BD tanto primarias como foráneas.

Que puede estar pasando?

Comment: prueba usar la ultima version de phpmyadmin sino usa el comando `mysqldump -u username -p database_name > backup_file.sql` para respaldar la base, este ultimo nunca falla

Comment: Revisa el archivo que genera el dump, si está comprimido lo puedes descomprimir y abrirlo incluso en un editor de texto tipo Notepad u otro, allí podrás ver lo que ocurre con tus tablas, si realmente están definidas las llaves primarias / foráneas, etc. Puede que las tablas estén en engine MyISAM, en cuyo caso las FK no funcionan realmente. Sea como sea, te aconsejo que aprendas a lidiar directamente desde la consola con la base de datos, PHPMyAdmin no es otra cosa que una interfaz gráfica, que a veces tiene limitaciones de versión y otros.

Comment: Revisar @A.Cedano por lo general creo que las creo en InnoDB pero como lo hago con el phpmyadmin, entonces realmente no estoy seguro como lo hace, me ha tocado 2 veces crear otra vez todas las llaves primarias, index y foraneas

Comment: @John, fijate que no veo el foreign_key_checks=1 que me habilita las llaves, tengo duda, yo se que es el mas fiable, pero me genero dudas con eso, pero tambien quiero hacer pruebas porque lo necesito para un backup en un servidor compartido ya la vez pasada habia hecho un cronjob pero no funciono.

Comment: insisto un `mysqldump -u username -p database_name > backup_file.sql` es la mejor forma de respaldar llaves foraneas y vistas que simpre fallan en algunas versiones de phpmyadmin